# Databinding a Custom Control

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have a Custom Control (Windows Form) that is a lookup text box. A property on the Control is Current Selection which is a Custom Object containing "Identifier", "Code" and "Description". This property is Databound using a BindingSource.

Displaying the information works great. On the other hand regardless of whether I set the Update to OnValidate or OnValueChange it never updates the BindingSource. Is there something I'm missing to get this to auto update?

```
private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource buildPlanComponentDataBindingSource;

    public void LoadBuildPlan(string itemNumber)
    {
        var buildPlanComponents = BuildPlan.LoadBuildPlanComponents(itemNumber, AutomaticPrice);
        buildPlanComponentDataBindingSource.DataSource = buildPlanComponents;
        AssemblyNumber = itemNumber;
    }




[Bindable(true)]
[DefaultValue(null)]
public ILookupSelection CurrentSelection
{
    get
    {
        if (currentSelection == null)
            currentSelection = new LookupSelection {Code = txtLookup.Text};

        return currentSelection;
    }

    set
    {
        if (value == null) return;

        currentSelection = value;

        SetText(currentSelection, DisplayText);
        SetDescription(currentSelection, DisplayDescription);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the code where you create the data binding?

Comment: Thanks, your question was very helpful.  For some reason, the MSDN tutorial left out the [Bindable(true)] attribute from its tutorial.  That's an important detail!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged seems to be the solution!

```
    #region IPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (null != PropertyChanged)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

Comment: IPropertyChanged should read INotifyPropertyChanged. I copied the code and got fooled by this detail when defining the inheritance. Otherwise this is great, +1

Answer (score 0):

> Displaying the information works
>   great. On the other hand regardless of
>   whether I set the Update to OnValidate
>   or OnValueChange it never updates the
>   BindingSource.

Looking at your code I'm actually not sure of this. In your set, you test for null and abandon; if the data actually contains null (which is what you're describing) your control will be out of synch. I wonder if perhaps that check is masking the underlying problem.

Comment: The only time that is really ever NULL is when the control is initially created. Otherwise this will only be set when a Selection is made which contains a value.

Comment: If that's the case then I would recommend you use a different flag to test, other than value == null. Databinding to properties is a back and forth process ... at any rate, I would clean this bit up, but I'm also not positive it'll help your problem in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to cause the DataBinding to write its value for each control whose value you are setting this way?

Assuming one data binding for a textbox named txtMySetValue:

txtMySetValue.DataBindings[0].WriteValue();